# После МНОГОКРАТНОГО перехода между вкладками не выводит информацию на php

Tags: php, link, вкладки

Здравствуйте!

Я новичок в php, когда я залогинился на сайт, кликаю на вкладку "мой профиль". Там описана моя информация, но после 6-7 очень быстрого:D перехода  по разным вкладкам, захожу снова во вкладку "мой профиль" и мне выдают ошибку типа:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://steamcommunity.com/id/bennysgaming//inventory/json/730/2)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.0 429 Unknown in V:\home\x.ru\www\myprofile.php on line
>   22

**Но через время почему-то снова код начинает правильно работать**

Сам код:

```
$a = $steamprofile['profileurl'];
$get_content = file_get_contents("$a/inventory/json/730/2");
$data_image = (array) json_decode($get_content) -> rgInventory;
$count_content = count($data_image);
$data_content = (array) json_decode($get_content, TRUE);
echo "Total items: $count_content <br><br>";
for ($i=0; $i<$count_content; $i++) {
    $element_name = array_shift($data_content[rgInventory]);
    $name_item = "$element_name[classid]_$element_name[instanceid]";
    echo "<img src='http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/";
    print_r($data_content['rgDescriptions'][$name_item]['icon_url']);
    echo "' style='width:90px; height:90px; float:left; margin: 5px; outline: 1px solid black;'>";
}
```

Я так понял, возникает проблема из-за того, что слишком много запросов за определенное время, как можно перефразировать данный код?

Comment: 1. Добавьте код, в котором возникает ошибка 2. Саму ошибку текстом напишите, а не картинкой

Comment: Вам надо было микроскоп приложить к вопросу, что бы разобрать что там в ошибке написано.

Comment: Обновил пояснение)

Comment: Еще блин непонятно, чего после `profileurl` добавляется лишний слеш `/` А если я побуду на другой вкладке мин 2-3, перехожу снова на `мой профиль` и код начинает нормально работать -_-

Comment: @Виталий Мммм... Сайт по `Каэске` пишите. Ох уж эти люди нетрадиционной ориентации (ладно шутка). Настоящие пацаны в `BF` шпарят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Статус ответа от сервера: 429 Too Many Requests «слишком много запросов». Значит вам нужно ограничить интервал опроса сайта. Предлагаю вам сделать кэш результата запроса к чужому сайту. Если дата кэша просрочена, загружаем данные ещё раз и кэшируем.

```
if (file_exists('cache.html') && time() - filemtime('cache.html') < 3600) {
    $content = file_get_contents('cache.html');
} else {
    $content = "Тут загружаем напрямую с сайта нужные нам данные";
    file_put_contents('cache.html', $content);
}

// Тут загруженные данные оформляем и выводим пользователю.
```

Comment: А ты не мог бы все это дать через код -_- Буду очень благодарен, все-таки я новичок в php

Comment: @Виталий, Обновил сообщение

Comment: Помоги еще раз:) Получилась такая функция: Если файл cache не существует, то идет кэш результата запроса к чужому сайту и создается этот файл + заносятся туда мне интересующие данные, но теперь я не знаю, как вывести те данные по моему выше сказанному коду т.к теперь данные выносятся только 1 раз, и то, если файла cache не существует

Comment: @Виталий, в вашем тексте темы есть ответ на свой вопрос. Вы сами написали код вывода, а теперь забыли, что вы его написали?

Comment: можно как-то теперь из файла взять эту информацию и занести в переменную?

Comment: Ну я все понял, пасибки:) Работает идеально, а что будет, если файл cache будет генерировать информацию не только для 1 человека? каждый раз создаваться для конкретного пользователя или изменять информацию в файле cahce , но тогда же она будет стирать информацию о предыдущем пльзователе. Даже если и будет информация записываться рядом, тогда как можно правильно считать информацию именно для 1 пользователся?

Comment: @Виталий, персональный кэш файл для каждого пользователя